# Living in country A and working for country B: Do I need a work permit in country A or will just nobody care?

Tags: working

Let's assume I live in Germany and I am registered there. But I have no right to work for whatever reason, e.g. I am on a student visa, I am a spouse on a dependent visa, I maybe a registered refugee, you name it.

In practice, nothing will hold me back from performing any remote digital work for anyone outside of Germany or even get employed as a remote worker by a company outside of Germany.

As I do live in Germany, my world income would be taxable in Germany. This is pretty clear.

But would I violate any labor / employment rules if I did that? If so, can you name them? I would like to understand if such a setup is legal or if it is not, just it would be extremely unlikely that anyone will notice.

Comment: (+1) Aren't refugees and spouses allowed to work in Germany?

Comment: It heavily depends on the actual status, this isn't black and white and often not easy. But as long as you define work = eymployment the answer (for non-EU nationals) in this case frequently is "no".